# VueDraggable Lock items

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuedraggable

I want some of the items to be locked and not be able to move. I saw in the documentation handle prop but this only disable dragging but if some other element which is able to be dragged go over will take his place.

```
<draggable
            :component-data="{ tag: 'ol', name: 'flip-list', type: 'transition' }"
            v-model="listItems"
            item-key="id"
            class="list-group"
            handle=".drag-icon"
            v-bind="dragOptions"
          >
            <template #item="{ element }">
              <li>
                <div class="box" :class="{'locked' : element.pinned}">
                <div class="box-value" >
                  <input type="checkbox" v-model="element.checked" class="checkbox" id="selectAll" @change="check(element)" :disabled="element.pinned"/>
                  <p>{{ element.visual }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-value">
                  <font-awesome-icon
                    class="icon"
                    :icon="['fas', 'lock']"
                    id="lock-icon"
                    v-if="element.pinned"
                  />
                  <font-awesome-icon
                    class="icon drag-icon"
                    :icon="['fas', 'arrows-up-down-left-right']"
                    id="drag-icon"
                    v-else
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              </li>
            </template>
          </draggable>
```